# Detect Nao robot in Kinect

Tags: kinect, nao-robot

I am not sure if this has been tried before but I am trying to use [Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) and detect gestures made by the [Nao robot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nao_%28robot%29).

I have made a Kinect application, [a gesture based picture viewer](http://youtu.be/v8SumS-I1qo) and it detects humans fine(Obviously it does!) What I wanted to try was (lazy as I am), to see if I could use some (say, voice) command to tell the Nao to do a Swipe Right gesture and have my application identify that gesture. The Nao can easily identify my command and do some gesture. The problem however is, when I put the Nao in front of the Kinect sensor, the Kinect does not track it.

What I want to know is, are there some basics behind Kinect's human body motion tracking that essentially fails when a robot is placed in front of it instead of a human?

PS: I have kept the Nao at the right distance from the sensor. I have also checked if the entire robot is in the field of view of the sensor.

Comment: Try placing the Nao with its arms extended, as in the Leonardo Man drawings.  The "right distance" for the robot may not be the same as for a human.  Also, using near mode may be applicable.

Comment: sorry my ignorance, whats "Nao"?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I tried changing the distances with its arms stretched  and then removed myself from the view, but still it did not detect Nao. I am beginning to wonder if its even possible.

Comment: @Ewerton [I love google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nao_(robot))

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the skeleton tracker has some assumptions of size associated with it.  It might see the Nao's joints, but realize that nobody is really that tiny so it just ignores the robot.  I'll see what I have of similar size to try out tomorrow or early next week.

Comment: Yeah, please do that and let me know what you come up with.

Comment: For those with access to the (currently private) [Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics) beta, this question has been [multi-posted there](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/148/37).

Comment: Yes but I wasnt sure if I should share that link.

Answer (score 1):

The NAO Robot doesn't have the same proportion as a human, and moreover its size is not of an human being (too short). For those reason, classic skeleton detection doesn't detect NAO as a human.

To do that you should take a current skeleton detection, than change threshold and constants. Sadly I don't hear about that kind of algorithm being opensource...

Just let me know...